# Set file permission to limit editing

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a application that involves multiple users.  The application is based on a spreadsheet.  After the user inputs information in the spreadsheet they click a button and a Google Doc template is copied and opened in a custom dialog and the user (author) writes a journal of their conclusions.  The author can come back to their doc file through the spreadsheet to add addition comments.

Now another user goes into the spreadsheet and want to see the other authors comments, but they shouldn't be able to edit just view.  The author is known and an admin is known but the other users may not be known at the time the file is created.  And the number of users that could view may increase as time goes on.

1)  What it the best way to set edit and view premission?
2)  What permission can give the admin the ability to delete the authors files?

I have also posted these questions on the Google App Script Community.

Comment: The question is too broad for this site, as it includes two question and also it's opinion based as it's asking for the best way without specific criteria to qualify something as the best.

Comment: @Rubén through app script a new file is created.  setSharing() is an all or none type of approach.  addEditor()/addViewer() requires a known list of users. Someone new comes along and has to be added to the list, and I believe adding an editor triggers the Review Permissions dialogs which I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you tested that? If not, create a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén if you use addEditor an email is sent to the email of the added user.  I tested with another user.  I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it specific by including the details you shared through comments and removing the second question. It's worthy to note posts that include a [mcve] usually are better received by the SO community.